# The best way to sort by custom index

Tags: python, django

I think about the best way to sort by index column.
I have model:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Category name"), max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    index = models.IntegerField(_("Index order"), default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can I set index on model level? In this case I would like let user to set order categories in menu.

Comment: You can order with `ProductCategory.objects.order_by('index')`.

Comment: Or you can set in the `class Meta`, the `ordering = ['index']`

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set index on model level?

You already have made a field index. You can also add a database index with the [**`db_index=True`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#db-index), to make it easier to order by and filter on the index:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Category name"), max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    index = models.IntegerField(_("Index order"), default=0, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can also specify that the model is by default ordered by the `index`, by specifing the [**`ordering`** option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#ordering):

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Category name"), max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    index = models.IntegerField(_("Index order"), default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['index']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*Unless* you specify the ordering explicitly (for example with `ProductCategory.objects.order_by('name')`), it will then order by `index`.